# AES Encryption to strange characters

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, encryption, aes

I am using AES Encryption in swift 3, I use this [CryptoSwift](https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift) library.
This is my code to encrypt a string and the result is readable string: `/QOEtrf3o8buv2wA9FeAyg==`.

How can I get the strange character (non readable) like this: `Ί�^��h��y^ғ`?

```
var input = "CryptoSwift"
var key = "passwordpassword"
var iv = "drowssapdrowssap"

func aesEncrypt(input: String, key: String, iv: String) throws -> String {
    let data = input.utf8
    let encrypted = try! AES(key: key, iv: iv, blockMode: .CBC, padding: PKCS7()).encrypt([UInt8](data))
    let encryptedData = Data(encrypted)
    return encryptedData.base64EncodedString()
}

let encrypted = try! aesEncrypt(input: input, key: key, iv: iv)
print("encrypted: \(encrypted)")
```

> ```
>   ---------
>
>     Result: /QOEtrf3o8buv2wA9FeAyg==
>
>     I want the result something like this: Ί�^��h��y^ғ, the strange characters.
> ```

Comment: � is a replacement character. Replacement is a way of indicating text corruption, the corruption typically being caused by reading text bytes with a character encoding other than what they were written with. That would be a bug. However, encrypted data is usually not text so reading it with any character encoding doesn't make sense. Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: hi @Tom Blodget, in android the result of encryption like "Ί�^��h��y^ғ". In android also can call base64 which is same result white iOS "/QOEtrf3o8buv2wA9FeAyg==". But the size of encrypted to "Ί�^��h��y^ғ is same with original file, but if we convert to base64 it will bigger then original

Comment: It is best to avoid using CryptoSwift, amoung other things it is 500 to 1000 times slower than Common Crypto based implementations. Apple's Common Crypto is FIPS certified and as such has been well vetted, using CryptoSwift is taking a chance on correctness and security.

Comment: It's fine to keep the result as binary if you can handle a byte array or binary file. But reading such bytes as text is an error. Base64 is a way of converting bytes to text in cases where binary cannot be present directly, such as in HTML and XML files. I see that you accepted an answer indicating that you can use a binary file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't convert it to Base64.

```
        let encrypted = try! AES(key: key, iv: iv, blockMode: .CBC, padding: PKCS7()).encrypt([UInt8](data))
        let encryptedData = Data(bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>(encrypted), count: Int(encrypted.count))
        // let encryptedString = String(data: encryptedData,encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        // use the encryptedData to write it into a file.
```

Comment: it returns nil @spaceMonkey

Comment: encryptedString still nil.

Comment: So the encrypted data in not a valid utf encoded it it will always be nil... Ί�^�� you can only see if you write the data into a file and open the file. So either u can convert to hex or base64

Comment: the result of let encrypted is like this = [253, 3, 132, 182, 183, 247, 163, 198, 238, 191, 108, 0, 244, 87, 128, 202] @spaceMonkey

Comment: So you only have 2 options to encode it.. Hex or base64

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144906/discussion-between-spacemonkey-and-imanuel-pardosi).

Comment: hi @spaceMonkey I try to save encryptedData to file, and it works. thanks bro.

Answer (score 2):

"Ί�^��h��y^ғ" isn't a proper string. The character "�" means "this isn't a character." (It's technical name is the "substitution character" that is used when a byte sequence is not valid for the Unicode-based encoding you're using). Since "�" could be many different byte sequences, "Ί�^��h��y^ғ" isn't really meaningful. There are a huge number of byte sequences that would decode into that nonsense string.

You're getting a "readable string" because you're encoding the random bytes that come out of the encryption function in [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

It's not really clear what you mean by "wanting" something that includes � (since that's nonsense). If you want the data, just return the `Data` (don't call `base64EncodedString()`). As a general rule, this is what you want to work with. Encrypted data is `Data`, it's not `String.

What are you trying to do that you want a nonsense string that has lost information in the encoding?

Comment: hi @Rob Napier, in android the result of encryption like "Ί�^��h��y^ғ". In android also can call base64 which is same result white iOS "/QOEtrf3o8buv2wA9FeAyg==". But the size of encrypted to "Ί�^��h��y^ғ is same with original file, but if we convert to base64 it will bigger then original.

Comment: "Ί�^��h��y^ғ" is not the data. That's a corrupted UTF-8 decoding of your the data. As you note in one of the comments, your actual data is [253, 3, 132, 182, 183, 247, 163, 198, 238, 191, 108, 0, 244, 87, 128, 202]. It looks like you've fixed your problem correctly now that you're no longer treating that a string (it isn't a string).

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a base64 encoded string which will always be readable ASCII. I'm unfamiliar with CryptoSwift, but if you can find some way to return the raw encrypted data, it should look the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I use it to properly decrypt and encrypt strings. You need to make string in hexString and hexString in data later. This is how CryptoSwift work.

```
extension String{
    func aesEncrypt(key: String, iv: String) throws -> String {
        let data = self.data(using: .utf8)!
        let encrypted = try! AES(key: key, iv: iv, blockMode: .CBC).encrypt([UInt8](data))
        let encryptedData = Data(encrypted)
        try? encryptedData.toHexString().aesDecrypt(key: key, iv: iv)
        return encryptedData.toHexString()
    }

    func aesDecrypt(key: String, iv: String) throws -> String {
        let data = self.dataFromHexadecimalString()!
        print(data)
        let decrypted = try! AES(key: key, iv: iv, blockMode: .CBC).decrypt([UInt8](data))
        let decryptedData = Data(decrypted)
        return String(bytes: decryptedData.bytes, encoding: .utf8) ?? "Could not decrypt"
    }


    func dataFromHexadecimalString() -> Data? {
        var data = Data(capacity: characters.count / 2)

        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[0-9a-f]{1,2}", options: .caseInsensitive)
        regex.enumerateMatches(in: self, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, characters.count)) { match, flags, stop in
            let byteString = (self as NSString).substring(with: match!.range)
            var num = UInt8(byteString, radix: 16)
            data.append(num!)

        }

        return data
    }
}


extension Data {

    public var bytes: Array<UInt8> {
        return Array(self)
    }

    public func toHexString() -> String {
        return self.bytes.toHexString()
    }
}
```